# Redgate SQL Data Generator -> Reviewing sqlgen project -> What does "Same as mapped data" mean?

Tags: sql, redgate, sqltools

I am reviewing a coworkers sqlgen job and I am unable to figure out what this means in the table generation settings.

Specify number of rows by:  "Same as mapped data"

My coworker has this selected on each table, I just need to know what is meant by this I have looked through documentation and been unable to find a definition for this.

I am on version 2 at the moment.  Probably not the best question but I need an answer and he is gone for a long period of time and our data is not working correctly with this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Same as mapped data" option is only available when you're using an existing table or view as a data source - it just means that the generator will insert all the rows from the source table or view. The other options are:

- Numeric value - a set number of rows
- Proportion of table - a proportion of the source table/view
- Generation time - as much data as the tool can generate in a set time

There's a little more about using an existing table/view as a data source [here](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content/SQL_Data_Generator/help/2.0/SDG_Mapping_SQL_tables_or_views) on the website, but it doesn't have much else useful in it.